# Vagrant - 2 VMs have same IP

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

Im trying to play around with puppet. So I fired up two debian instances using vagrant. My Vagrantfile looks like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "puppetagent" do |puppetagent|
    puppetagent.vm.box = "puphpet/debian75-x64"
    puppetagent.vm.hostname = "puppetagent.example.com"
    puppetagent.vm.network "private_network",ip: "192.168.10.21"
  end

  config.vm.define "puppetmaster" do |puppetmaster|
    puppetmaster.vm.box = "puphpet/debian75-x64"
    puppetmaster.vm.hostname = "puppetmaster.example.com"
    puppetmaster.vm.network "private_network",ip: "192.168.10.22"
  end
```

However when I ssh into both the instances, and look into `/etc/hosts` the files (on both ) look like this:

```
# master - instance1

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1 puppetmaster.example.com puppetmaster

# agent - instance2

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1 puppetagent.example.com puppetagent
```

Im confused regarding this. I did specify diff IP's for both, but why does it show same IP's in the `hosts` file?

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/255835/whats-a-loopback-address-i-e-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could I hazard a guess that you are running a debian based VM?

The 127.0.1.1 line, although not a debian specifity *per se* is added by the debian installer as is explained on the [debian manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution). Not all Unices do so.

This is loopback addres, nothing to do with the actual IP adress from your VM, regardless if you are using debian or not.

If you want to have /etc/hosts updated by vagrant, you will need to use a plugin like [Vagrant hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager).

Comment: Yes I am using debian.